# The Overworld Map on M&B Warband automatically moves for me, help!

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

So I've been trying to get into this game, and it's amazing so far, however the overworld map has a bug which I cannot get rid of.

In short, the game is behaving as if I'm constantly holding down the A and S keys whilst on the overworld map. I can cancel the movement by holding down W and D constantly, but I can't move in those directions as they are being cancelled out by the phantom A and S.

I have unplugged all input devices except for my keyboard and mouse, and I am also not just leaving my mouse in the corner of the screen or something which might cause it to move.

I have downloaded this from steam and I don't want a seemingly great game to go to waste due to a small bug like this!

Comment: Does it have controller support?

Comment: Are you in full screen or windowed mode?

Answer (score 1):

If someone else ever encounters this problem, make sure that you have no other input devices, such as a controller, plugged into your computer. It may take the input from that device instead of your actual keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few fixes I would recommend:

-Start by viewing the game from the Steam Library, Right Click on it, Select Properties, Local Files Tab, Verify Integrity of Game Cache Button.  This may take a couple of minutes.

-Second [Before launching the game] go ahead and do a system reset with your Keyboard unplugged.  Once rebooted and on your Windows Screen (Assuming you run Windows) plug in the Keyboard and test before launching game.

-If all else fails (Although you have probably already tried this) uninstall and reinstall the game.

I hope this helps!  I'm a huge fan of the M&B Series and hope you get to play!

Answer (score 0):

That's a common problem with Mount&Blade that gets easily solved by pressing those "phantom" keys once. For example, if the game thinks you are pressing W, press W once with the game on, and it will usually go away.